# How to find the boundary condition in method of Separation of variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am trying to find the solution of the following Initial boundary- value problem.
\begin{equation*}
u_t = k \Delta u ~~~~~~0<x<1,~~~~ 0<y<1 ~~~~,0<t<1
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
u(x,y,0)= u_0(x,y)~~~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1, ~~0\leq y \leq 1\\
u(0,y,t)=u(1,y,t)=cos(\pi y)~~~~~ 0\leq t \leq 1, ~~0\leq y \leq 1\\
u_y(x,0,t)=u_y(x,1,t)=0~~~~~ 0\leq t \leq 1, ~~0\leq x \leq 1\\
\end{equation*}

My attempt: By the method of separation of variables, we may assume a non trivial separable solution in the form
\begin{equation*}
u(x,y,t)=U(x,y)T(t)
\end{equation*}
Substituting this into the give PDE, we get
\begin{equation*}
T' + \lambda k T=0\\
\Delta U +\lambda U =0
\end{equation*}

I assume a non trivial separable solution in the form $U(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, then we have
\begin{equation*}
X''-\mu X=0\\
Y''+(\lambda + \mu)Y =0
\end{equation*}
Because the conditions in x are homogenous, we choose $\mu = -\alpha^2$ so that
\begin{equation*}
X''+\alpha^2 X=0\\
X(x)= A ~cos(\alpha x) +B~ sin(\alpha y)
\end{equation*}

Now we have,

\begin{equation*}
u(0,y,t)=cos(\pi~ y) \implies U(0,y)T(t) = cos(\pi~y)\\
\implies X(0)Y(y) = cos (\pi~y) = X(1)Y(y)\\
X(0)=X(1)=1\\
Y(y) = cos(\pi~y)
\end{equation*}

I am little confused in the calculation of boundary conditions here.

Can anyone suggest the solution of the boundary condition here?

Comment: I believe you have to use Fourier series when the BC are nonhomogeneous.

Comment: @innerproduct do you mean firstly I write $u(x,y,t)$ in term of Fourier series, then apply these conditions to the $u(x,y,t)$?

Comment: Yes. You can directly apply the BC for the ODE in $Y$ because they're homogeneous. Then solve the ODEs for $X$ and $T$ in terms of unknown constants. Then write as Fourier series and apply the nonhomogeneous BC. Some examples are given here: https://faculty.uca.edu/darrigo/Students/M4315/Fall%202005/sep-var.pdf, although I think they only do one spatial dimension.

Comment: @innerproduct, I get $X(x)= A cos(\alpha x) +B sin(\alpha x)$, $Y_n(y) = c_n cos( n \pi y)$ and $T_n(t) = E_n e^{-(\alpha^2 +(n \pi)^2)kt}$, How do I write $X(x)$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: Did you mean to write $u_y(x,1,t)=0$ in the last boundary condition? Otherwise you have conflicting conditions at two of the corners of the square.

Comment: @HansLundmark I used this condition $(u_y(x,1,t)=0$. I was thinking to use $u(0,y,t)=cos(\pi y)$ in the end.

Comment: That's not what I meant. In your statement of the problem, it says $u(x,1,t)=0$, and I'm asking if it's really supposed to be like that, or if you meant $u_y(x,1,t)=0$? (With $u_y$, not $u$.)

Comment: Thank you. That was a typo.

Comment: OK, good. It makes more sense now!